# laravel routing in web.php for self referring table

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, self-reference

I am using laravel 5.6 
I have a self referring table called "directory"

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(null)->nullable();
$table->string('folder', 64);
$table->timestamps();
$table->unique(['parent_id', 'folder']);
```

For a root directory the "parent_id" will be null

How to create a resource route in web.php ? Something like:

```
Route::resource('directory.childdirectory','DirectoryController')->name('directory', 'dir_root_id', 'dir_child_id');
```

Is there any example CRUD for self referential relation?

How can a create a resource route in web.php for a self referential relationship?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in short for a self referring table was how to pass the "parent" and "child" id to the controller. I did that by defining a resource controller in the routing table (web.php for laravel 5.6) with an additional parameter {id}

```
Route::resource('{id}/directory', 'directoryController');
```

Command php artisan route:list will look like the code below, where {id} is the parent directory and {directory} is the child directory

```
| POST      | {id}/directory                     | directory.store
| GET|HEAD  | {id}/directory                     | directory.index
| GET|HEAD  | {id}/directory/create              | directory.create
| GET|HEAD  | {id}/directory/{directory}         | directory.show
| PUT|PATCH | {id}/directory/{directory}         | directory.update
| DELETE    | {id}/directory/{directory}         | directory.destroy
| GET|HEAD  | {id}/directory/{directory}/edit    | directory.edit
```